# Como uso variáveis dentro desse código PHP + MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

Meu código retorna o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a2015539/public_html/envio.php on line 28

O código é este:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sexo, dia, mes, ano)
VALUES ('"$nome"','"$sexo"','"$dia"','"$mes"','"$ano"')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New record created successfully');</script>";
} else {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
}

$conn->close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erro de digitação. Você não concatenou os valores.

Solução:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sexo, dia, mes, ano)
VALUES ('".$nome."','".$sexo."','".$dia."','".$mes."','".$ano."')";
```

Vale dizer que os dados precisam ser sanitizados antes da inserção:

```
$nome_sanitizado = $conn->real_escape_string( $nome );
```

E ao inserir algo como:

```
"..... VALUES ('".$nome_sanitizado."',
```

Isto evita corrupção da *query* em valores com aspas e caracteres especiais, e minimiza a chance de Injeção de SQL

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Bacco

Answer (score 2):

altere essa linha

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sexo, dia, mes, ano)
VALUES ('"$nome"','"$sexo"','"$dia"','"$mes"','"$ano"')";
```

para

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sexo, dia, mes, ano)
VALUES ('".$nome."','".$sexo."','".$dia."','".$mes."','".$ano."')";
```

os pontos servem para unir suas variáveis com as strings

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Italo Rodrigo